# How do I tell if CPU Turbo is on or not on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, intel-cpu

I'm  using a command that has been recommended to me many times and all it turns up is this:

```
user@tux:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
user@tux:~$
```

But from what was said it should say intel-pstate instead

I'm running a `core i7 Q 720 @1.60 GHz`, its max is 2.80 GHZ, but I don't know if turbo is on or not. When playing games like garrys mod, im running at up to 85 degrees celsius. help? please?

my laptop is a lenovo ideapad y560.

EDIT: also linux only seems to detect 2 cores, but i have a quad core according to intel.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the out put of `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`. It does seems that you should have 4 cores, but we need the exact model name to be able to check for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is using the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequnecy scaling driver instead of the intel-pstate CPU frequency scaling driver because your particular processor chip pre-dates anything the Intel driver was designed for.

Even with the apci-cpufreq driver you can determine if your CPUs are going into turbo frequencies by observation. Do `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`.